# Issue refreshing UI, validation error message on button click

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox

We need to update validation messages on button click, so we need to refresh the UI. What we do is to fire `OnPropertyChanged` with empty strings. This worked for me to update validation messages but some comboboxes start resetting their values on UI refresh. The combobox whose itemsource is set dynamically is resetting its value to null but it has value in model. If someone have any ideas then please help.

Comment: [Please show us code that demonstrates some specific problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please paste the code as text into your question and format it correctly. Nobody can possibly answer the question as you've asked it.

Comment: Firing a `PropertyChanged` event with an empty string will cause an update of all bound properties in the UI. You might want to consider updating only the values you need to update.